# Index solr, return suggestions one word at a time

Tags: solr, autocomplete

I want to make an index with solr for autosuggestion in a web application.

The user is supposed to be able to search for a product in a web shop.

When a search is made i want the suggestion to be precented one word at a time.

So if i write "Pe" than "Peak Performance" and others with the same starting frace is suggested.

If i continue writing for example "Sh" than the suggestion will be "Peak Performance Shirt"

If i continue writing "Peak Performance Shirt B" than "Peak Performance Shirt Blue"  is suggested and so on.

What i have tried so fare is to create documents like this:

```
<entity name="p" query="SELECT * FROM Products">  

  <field column="ProductName" name="user_query"/> 

  <field column="Mark" name="mark"/>  

</entity>
```

What happens is that the whole document is suggested when Solr find a match.

Is there a way not to suggest the whole document up front, just one word at a time?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not an autosuggestion, but you are running an actual search every time, that is why you get the result from the search back.

An autocomplete must be run against a different field that contains all the possible wirds you want to suggest.

Build a field called "suggestions" that will contain for example the terms: 
    Peak
    Peak Performance
    Peak Performance Shirt 
    Peak Performance Shirt Blue

(this can be achieved in many ways and with different filters)

Now run the autocomplete against the "suggestions" field. you will get the result you are expecting.

Then simply get the result and use it to run the actual search on the Products field.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that it's helpful to create a different RequestHandler for the autocomplete, even if it's pulling from the same index.  That way you can define which fields are queried, and what is returned - that way an autocomplete result won't look like a search result, and it will hopefully be a bit faster.

To match against partial words, you probably want to populate a field using the [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) on a field type like this:

```
 <fieldType name="startswith" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

Comment: Can i combine calls to different handlers using jQuery autocomplete from one and the same textbox?